# Ubuntu 18.04.4 screen color temperature keeps reverting

Tags: 18.04, temperature

I was using `sct` earlier and also tried `redshift` to change the screen color temperature to the desired level. However, now it keeps reverting to the default color for some reason. Although I am aware of the "Night Light" settings, it is not suitable for me. Can anyone suggest some alternative or fix, please?

Answer (score 0):

The programs are working fine, the  "Night Light" got switched ON somehow without my knowledge and was interfering with the changing screen color temperature.